# JPA / MySQL Decimal displayed in wrong way

Tags: mysql, jpa, precision

I want to persist a sum of double values as Decimal(4,2) in my database and display it to the user. The issue I have is, that the decimal number is stored correctly in my database with two decimal digits. But when querying it from the database in some cases it displays a lot more decimal digits to the user.
In my Entity class I have:

```
@Column(name="weight_sum", precision=6, scale=2)
    private double weightSum;
```

In my MySQL Database I have a column specified as

```
Decimal (4,2)
```

I don't understand where I made the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are doing correct things but you need to do some more stuff.
If you have define precision and scale for weightSum of entity class then it will save into db accordingly.
But when you get back data from db and bind to corresponding entity class then it will again take default scale(actual scale following by zero) and precision value.
So whenever you send data to end user you need to set scale as-

`weightSum.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR)`;

In above method 2nd parameter is `roundingMode`, you should select roundingMode as per your requirement.

I hope it will help you out. Thanks